# "Show that between any two roots of $\sin(x)$, there is at least one root of $\cos(x)$"

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

"Show that between any two roots of $\sin(x)$, there is at least one root of $\cos(x)$".

I want to confirm that I'm using the right strategy for this proof. First we need to show that the sine function, call it $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere, and therefore continuous everywhere. The key property of $f$ at this point is that $$f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)f'(h)+f'(x)f(h)-f(x)$$

, and it can be shown that the limit is precisely $f'(x)=\cos(x)$. Let $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $a,b \in [a,b]$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Now we can use Rolle's Theorem and claim that  there is a point $c\in (a,b)$, such that $$f'(c)=0$$

and since $c \in (a,b)$, we have that $a<c<b$. Is there something wrong with this proof?

Comment: Your proof looks fine.

Comment: The proof is valid. The derivate of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ and the conditions for Rolle's theorem are satisfied. Hence you can conlcude the claim this way.

Comment: What is "$a,b \in [a,b]$" trying to convey?  It appears vacuously true.

Comment: When $f$ is differentiable everywhere then between any two roots of $f$ there is a root of $f'$, by Rolle's theorem.